# How tight should I make body panels?

Tags: torque, body-work

Car is a civic vti 99.

I don't believe body panels have a recommended torque setting, am I right?

If you fit body parts loosely or tightly will both be ok or might they fly off when driving?  I've been turning until they are loosely tight and then I just push it 5 mm more and I think this is considered hand tight.  However I notice i can actually apply force and keep pushing for a while.  Today I discovered one of the bolts I did yesterday were loose though this could have been due to placing the wrong bolt. size.

Comment: Really, they should be tight. Tight just shy of the point where you'll strip or break something. Hand tight will encourage stuff to fall off. If you're not looking for a weight reduction program for you car, don't go hand tight ... make them *tight*.

Comment: The key to knowing how tightly a fastener should be is to turn it until the head snaps off, then back off a half turn.

Comment: @fred_dot_u how does one know a fastener head has snapped off? Is it when the cracking sound comes?  I heard and felt this however I thought I was damaging something so I laid off.  i thought I was damaging because I previously done the same on plastic and it cracked. Are you saying it's ok to do on steel?

Comment: @JamesWilson fred_dot_u was joking.  Don't over-tighten them, you will either break or weaken the fasteners.  The bolts need to be tight, but knowing how tight is something you just get a feel for with experience. Unless torque settings are specified you need to use your judgement based on the size of the fastener and what it is made of.